# open text file after user login java

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project for school that is due tonight and have exhausted my resources. I am required to build an authentication program for a zoo that allows an employee to login with limited attempts. After a successful login it is suppose to display their text file according to their role in the fourth column.

griffin.keyes   108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet soup" zookeeper

rosario.dawson  3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    "animal doctor" admin

bernie.gorilla  a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    "secret password"   veterinarian

donald.monkey   17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3    "M0nk3y business"   zookeeper

jerome.grizzlybear  3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900    "grizzly1234"   veterinarian

bruce.grizzlybear   0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7    "letmein"   admin

I have successful login, limited to 3 attempts, and the option to logout and exit, but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't loading their role files accordingly.. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

```html
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AuthenticationSystem {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Scanner scan;
            scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Zane Hewgley\\Desktop\\AuthSys\\.idea\\credentials.txt"));
            String credentials[][] = new String[100][4];
            int count = 0;
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
//read file
                credentials[count][0] = scan.next();
                credentials[count][1] = scan.next();
//obtain credentials from file
                String l[] = scan.nextLine().split("\"[ ]+");
                l[0] = l[0].trim();
                l[0] = l[0].replace("\"", "");

                credentials[count][2] = l[0];
                credentials[count][3] = l[0].trim();
                count++;
            }
//request user input
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean RUN = true;
            int tries = 0;

            while (RUN) {
                System.out.println("-Welcome-");
                System.out.println("1-Login");
                System.out.println("2-Exit");

                int ch = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());

                if (ch == 1) {
//increment number of attempts
                    tries++;
//request username and password
                    System.out.print("Username: ");
                    String username = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Password: ");
                    String password = input.nextLine();
//generate hash
                    MessageDigest md;
                    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    md.update(password.getBytes());
                    byte[] digest = md.digest();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (byte b : digest) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                    }
                    String hPassword = sb.toString();

                    boolean badUser = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        if (username.contentEquals(credentials[i][0])) {
                            if (hPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1])) {
//if verified, logged in
                                List<String> data = null;
//check type of user and print
                                switch (credentials[i][3]) {
                                    case "zookeeper":
                                        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("zookeeper.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                        break;
                                    case "admin":
                                        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("admin.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                        break;
                                    case "veterinarian":
                                        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("veterinarian.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                if (data != null) {
                                    for (String s : data) {
                                        System.out.println(s);
                                    }
                                }
//reset
                                tries = 0;

                                System.out.println("\n1) Logout.");
                                System.out.println("2) Exit.");

                                ch = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());
                                if (ch == 2) {
                                    RUN = false;
                                }
                                badUser = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (badUser) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Username or password.");
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
//limit attempts
                if (tries == 3) {
                    RUN = false;
                    System.out.println("Immoderate attempts!");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are the files not read, not found or not displayed? Any error messages?

Comment: I think he said he is unable to open txt files to group role, is that correct? If so can you try to open one file just try simple code and let us know. If that is not the case let us know as well

Comment: My apologies, I should've stated that. I'm not getting anymore errors and to be honest I am not even sure if the files are being read. I do know the credentials.txt file is because it is verifying the users and allowing successful login. After I log in, the only thing it say is 1-Logout 2-Exit

Comment: And just an FYI, I have only been using java for about 7 weeks. So this in its entirety is still new to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you split the array information:

```
        String l[] = scan.nextLine().split("\"[ ]+");
        l[0] = l[0].trim();
        l[0] = l[0].replace("\"", "");
```

you go on to write the result - which is the password - in credentials[count][3]; so this will later contain the password when you check if it is a zookeper, etc.

Above you have fixed lengths; if you use that, you could split up the line like this:

```
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            credentials[count][0] = line.substring(0, 20).trim();
            credentials[count][1] = line.substring(20, 55).trim();
            credentials[count][2] = line.substring(55, 74).trim();
            credentials[count][3] = line.substring(74).trim();
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge in this, but how would I do that? Is it too much to ask for an example?

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 74
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
 at AuthenticationSystem.main(AuthenticationSystem.java:21)

Comment: Do you have the exact format of credentials.txt that you have given in the question? If not you need to adjust the positions of the fixed length positions...

Comment: No another user edited it, but I'll plug the numbers in and rerun it here shortly. Idk why I didn't think of that.

Comment: So I just reformatted the credentials file and that error ceased, but now I have this

Username: griffin.keyes
Password: alphabet soup
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: zookeeper.txt
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)

(9 other repetitive errors)

at AuthenticationSystem.main(AuthenticationSystem.java:66)

Comment: Nevermind, incorrect file path. Thank you so much for the guidance!!